# Query/filter multiple taxonomies in Joomla

Tags: joomla, navigation, filtering, taxonomy, joomla-extensions

I am trying to create a recruitment site in Joomla with multiple taxonomies (sector, salary range, etc) and need to have a page listing all jobs with the ability to filter (or drill down) the jobs/articles based on the taxonomies.

I have seen a Wordpress plugin called [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshots/) that does exactly what I want but I need a similar solution for Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can get the job done:

1. Custom code a job board solution
2. Use a CCK like, Sebolt, Zoo, K2, Flexicontent
3. Use http://jobboard.joomlart.com/